# Inserting Calendar items in Android ICS

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider

For one of my application we have to insert an event into calendar.

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0;     
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 8, 10, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 8, 10, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, values);
// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
Log.d("MainActivity", "addCalendarEvents :: " + "eventID :: "+eventID);

Cursor cursor = cr.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, null, Events.TITLE +"='Jazzercise'", null, null);
Log.d("MainActivity", "addCalendarEvents :: " + "cursor :: "+cursor.getCount());
```

Provided on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html
However, firstly it gives me a error

```
 Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
```

Also the cursor count is zero. When i try to search with the title. 
Note: I tried using the intents service to add events, however I don't want user discretion while adding the event.

I have tested it on a Galaxy Nexus (4.1) and Nexus S(4.1).

Any help with the correct UI which is to be used with ICS?

BR,
Jayshil

Comment: Note: I don't get a explicit crash or error.

Comment: If someone from the dev community try this in a 4.0 ICS device that would be really helpful. If its a Jellybean issue or 4.0 and above issue.

Comment: This error appeared after the jellybean update, I have the same issue on a nexus 7. On ICS my code worked, after the update it stopped and logcat reports the line you quoted. It then offers com.google.android.calendar as an alternative but if I replace this in my code, this still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out. The line:

```
Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
```

**is a complete red herring (i.e. irrelevant).** It's simply some framework code that performs infrastructural work, [as seen here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#4454).

---

The problem lies in the documentation - if you're like me, you probably expected `long calID = 3;` to be some valid Calendar ID. **It's not a valid ID, it's a placeholder for the sake of documentation**.

What you're doing with the code above, if you're using an empty emulator, is inserting an entry into a non-existent calendar, i.e. nowhere visible.

What you need is to:

1. [Query for and choose an existing calendar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#query). Once again - **on the emulator, there is no default calendar**.
2. Use the obtained actual calendar ID to insert the event.

In short - the documentation and debug messages are not idiot-proof enough ;).

Comment: loved the last line.. i just found the same solution couple of days back.. And have to hand it to you...

Comment: in between the latest doc are much better.. they first let you query the calendars and then show how to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct permissions in the Manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

That might be part of the cause of the error you're seeing.

Comment: Yes i do have those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
content://com.android.calendar - problem is here.
```

Its calenders.

Try with this code:

```
Uri mCalendarsUri;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
    mCalendarsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
} else {
    mCalendarsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
}
```